# Unable to install Ubuntu or any other distro Alongside Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

How do I proceeded with Ubuntu installation?

- Made my USB drive bootable with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).
- Restart and booted from USB.
- I see the Ubuntu installation window, clicked next, selected both options *Download updates* and the MP3 thing and clicked next.
- I get options like *Erase & install Ubuntu* and something else where I manually create partitions for Ubuntu.
- Erase is not an option for me so I selected "something else" and clicked next.
- Here I only see my Whole drive as `sda0` and nothing else, I don't see my different partitions that I have when I'm on windows.

[image: Screenshot]